# Boostrap Responsive gives me a horizontal scroll bar on FF, Chrome, Safari browser now - need to fix it

Tags: browser, twitter-bootstrap

http://colelatimer.com/archive/dl/docs/results-alt.html

Suddenly, I have a horizontal scroll bar appearing now, I didn't before. Can anyone help me figure it out?

I'd also like to figure out how to make the subnav tag I have on the page (in gray) to stretch across the entire page, but when I resize the page down, the right side of the gray bar over stretches to the right of the page content. If I give the subnav 100% width, it stops short of the full page width (960) by 20 pixels due to the padding added in the original bootstrap code; however, I'm not sure how to have it stretch the full width, without also messing with the padding that affects the other (top) nav bar.

I might submit two different questions. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The code in your footer is mangled and causing the horizontal bar.

It should be something like -

```
<div class="blue-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
      <a href="http://www.tufts.edu" title="Tufts.edu" target="_new">
      <img src="../docs/assets/img/tuftsuniversity.png" alt="Go to tufts.edu" width="173" height="61" border="0"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="span2 offset10"><span style="color:#ffffff;line-height:150%;">&copy; 2012 Tufts University</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Specifically it was the offset10 that was causing the bar.  If you offset the total of the offset and span should equal 12.  Also, you were missing a closing div for the first row.

Comment: You can mix the two rows and use the `pull-right` bootstrap declaration for cleaner (and proper) results. Two rows in one line is not proper use of the bootstrap grid.